# Spring - Converting between classes implicitly (Looking to enforce a pattern)

Tags: java, spring

I am looking to enforce a pattern between two sets of classes (Let's call them Beans and Models), in such a way that they can be converted between each other without explicit code in each of the Bean/Model PoJo (Let's call this assembler).

I thought of creating Base classes for Beans, Models and Assemblers, and calling the assemblers method from the base class, so each of the Bean and Model would get the convert method implicitly.

Something like this:

```
BaseBean[BaseAssembler a, convertToModel(BaseBean b){a.convertToModel(b)}]
BaseModel[BaseAssembler a, convertToBean(BaseModel m){a.convertToBean(m)}]
BaseAssembler[convertToBean(BaseModel m), convertToModel(BaseBean b)]
```

Then I'd create a set of concrete classes:

```
EmpBean[name,id] extends BaseBean
EmpModel[name,id] extends BaseModel
EmpAssembler[convertToBean(EmpModel m),convertToModel(EmpBean b)] implements BaseAssembler
```

Now, I want to call `empBean.convertToModel()` and get an instance of `EmpModel`. But in reality, all I get is a `NPE` on the `assembler.convertToModel()` call.

Any Ideas on how to tell Spring that `EmpBean` and `EmpModel` use `EmpAssembler` and not `BaseAssembler`?

EDIT:
I am using annotation based configuration and trying to solve this issue without reverting to XML based configuration. If I were using XML configuration, I am guessing the easy solution would be to just set the concrete class as the value of the assembler. Something like below:

```
<bean id="empAssembler" class="com.blah.EmpAssembler" />
<bean id="deptAssembler" class="com.blah.DeptAssembler" />

<bean id="empBean" class="com.blah.EmpBean" >
    <property name="assembler" ref="empAssembler" />
</bean>

<bean id="empModel" class="com.blah.EmpModel" >
    <property name="assembler" ref="empAssembler" />
</bean>

<bean id="bookBean" class="com.blah.BookBean" >
    <property name="assembler" ref="bookAssembler" />
</bean>

<bean id="bookModel" class="com.blah.BookModel" >
    <property name="assembler" ref="bookAssembler" />
</bean>
```

How can I achieve this with annotation based configuration?

Comment: Use Spring DI to inject the Assembler...?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to do that, but I can't do that in the sub classes, since I don't want every Pojo to have an instance of the assembler, and I can't do it in the BaseClass because, how would I inject implementing classes, which the super class doesn't know about?

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for something using the `ConversionService`?

Comment: Oh, this is new to me. I will have to look into this, but looks like something I could use.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to call `empBean.convertToModel()` and not `empBean.getModel()`.

Please put some concrete code here how EmpBean inherits from BaseBean and how it is initialized. Then it should be easy to see.

Without that I can just take a wild guess:

1. The `NPE` hints that you missed initializing BaseBean.a
2. Another reason might be "shadowing" if EmpBean has its own EmpBean.a:

If your class EmpBean looks like this:

```
class EmpBean extends BaseBean {
    EmpAssembler a;
    EmpBean(EmpAssembler a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
}
```

then EmpBean.a "shadows" BaseBean.a which means there are two instances of `a`:
`this.a` is initialized with some instance in the constructor but `super.a` is still `null`. And `BaseBean.convertToModel(...)` only knows the latter.
If this is your problem then you just have to remove `EmpAssembler a;`

Responding to you comment:
If constructor-injection is not an option, you might want to try annotation-based setter injection. Something like:

```
@Autowired
void setAssembler(EmpAssembler a) {
    this.a = a;
}
```

Comment: I know what you're saying, and for a time, the shadowing is what was causing this issue. So, I removed the assembler property from the concrete classes. But I do not want to do constructor injection since it may lead to issues with jackson when the @RequestBody is converted to the EmpModel class. Look at the update I made to my question with the xml based configuration. TBH, I just want a solution to do the same without an XML.

Comment: Maybe setter-injection is the way to go for you. I appended some code to my answer.